# add 2 different paramters to ann URL and return a custom response

Tags: python, json

i'm still new in python,
I'd like to return a URI which accepts my 2 paramaters,which are input (target_group_id, date), this is my base url, get_customer_action_by_target_group_url = 'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=&date=' and this is my function.

```
def get_customer_action_by_target_group(self):
    payload = {"TargetGroupID": "%s" % self.TargetGroupID, "Date":"%s" % self.date,
                }
    if not self.TargetGroupID or not self.date:
        get_target_group_id = (raw_input("Please provide the target Group id:"))
        get_date = (raw_input("Please provide the date as required:"))
        self.TargetGroupID = get_target_group_id
        self.date = get_date
    response = self.send_request(self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url + self.TargetGroupID +
                                  self.date,
                                 json.dumps(payload), "GET")
    print response, response.text, response.reason
    return response
```

This should pass the paramters in my url which needs to look like this: 
https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=19&date=20 july 2017 After passing the date and the target groupe_id , but i'm getting this rather https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=%25s&date=%25s7220%20July%202017. How could i fixe this ? any sample of code which could help??  Thank   you

Answer (score 1):

I assume your base string is 'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=%25s&date=%25s' and then your code should be

```
def get_customer_action_by_target_group(self):
    payload = {"TargetGroupID": "%s" % self.TargetGroupID, "Date":"%s" % self.date
            }
    if not self.TargetGroupID or not self.date:
        get_target_group_id = (raw_input("Please provide the target Group id:"))
        get_date = (raw_input("Please provide the date as required:"))
        self.TargetGroupID = get_target_group_id
        self.date = get_date
    response = self.send_request(self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url % (self.TargetGroupID, self.date)
                             json.dumps(payload), "GET")
    print response, response.text, response.reason
    return response
```

then pyton will replace both values of %s in the original link with the values in self.TargetGroupID and self.date

Furthermore the part 20%20July%202017 is as expected since in an URI a space is escaped by %20 so it says 20 July 2017.

Comment: No base string is https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup?targetGroupID=&date=

Comment: @Hendriks, did you check it ??

Comment: Then you probably need to split the basu url at the &.

Comment: Hi  K. Hendriks what do you  mean by split a the & ?

Comment: fisrt, second = self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url.split('&')
response = self.send_request(first + self.TargetGroupId + second + self.date, json.dumps(payload), "GET")